# Specific Parabolic Equation with Two Known Points and a known point of diminishing returns

Tags: conic-sections

I am looking for a specific parabola that is horizontal opening toward -x (So a backward C).  All of the values in this scenario concern Quadrant 1, and have these rules:

1. y-values are whole numbers.
2. Point 1 is (185, 1), and is slightly -x,+y from the vertex
3. Point 2 is (85, 40), Further -x,+y from the vertex, this is the point of diminishing returns going negative.
4. If you multiply the coordinate pair values, the total should get higher as x decreases, and y increases from 1 to 40 (up and to the left), but any multiplication of y=41 and higher should begin to lower.

So:

- (y=1) * (x=185) = 185
- (y=2) * x > 185
- (y=3) * x > 2x
- 4x > 3x
- ...
- (y=40) * (x=85) = 3400
- (y=41) * x < 3400
- (y=42) * x < 41x
- ...

I found this equation which is close: `x = 185 - y^2/16`, but it caps at the coordinate where y=32 : (121, 32) and begins to lower from there, so I'm not quite there.

I may need to solve this again for two different points, so knowing a tool or process to solve it would be wonderful.  But my requirement right now is this specific scenario.

Comment: You have three (incompatible) conditions for two unknowns, impossible to find an exact solution.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Do you know of a graph visualizer for Horizontal-Vertex parabolas that can help me to see that and play with the numbers?  I may have to make exceptions.